# Eclipse Juno spell check strange behavior

Tags: eclipse, pydev, spell-checking

I am trying to setup eclipse Juno to do spell checking with a custom dictionary (to do Spanish spell checking). When I enable spell checking I get errors on every Spanish word, because the English dictionary detects them as wrong.

I have seen several guides on this topic and they all point to the same solution; add a user defined dictionary with the Spanish words, and disable the English dictionary. So I proceed to set it up like the following picture:

[image]

But it didn't work (no words were detected as incorrect), so on the 'Platform dictionary' dropdown, I selected 'US english' to re-enable the english dictionary. Like this:

[image]

Now the Spanish words are detected as wrong again. BUT, the interesting point is that I have a user dictionary file defined, so if I add a Spanish word to the dictionary, I can see the dictionary file to check if that word has been added. So there we go.

The end of the original dictionary file:

[image]

The code with the incorrectly spelled word:
[image]

The end of the dictionary file after adding the word 'Pedro':
[image]

Anybody have a clue of what's going on here?. I would expect the word 'Pedro' to be added at the end of the file, but I am getting these strange characters instead. Although, that explains why none of the words already present in the dictionary are being recognized.

I have tried different file encoding settings, but that made no difference.

Help please!

Comment: did you try to change the encoding in Content Types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably that your dictionary file is encoded in UTF-8. Try to change encoding setting in Eclipse to UTF-8.

Comment: The file was encoded in UCS-2, changing the encoding to UTF-8 both in the file and in eclipse solved the problem. Thanks!